# Display Image on top left corner of the desktop

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to display a very small image on the top left corner of the windows desktop, it will be a picture of a small note and when you mouse over it, the window will show.

How can I do this in C#?

- There should be no borders or regular window graphics
- The image will be partially transparent
- When a mouse over event occurs a window will display
- The image will always overlay other windows

Thanks

Comment: Use WinForms or WPF...shouldn't be that hard to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to point you to the right direction for each of those requirements, you can do more research on how to exactly achieve each one using google or stackoverflow.com

You need to create a widows form, and add the image as the background of the form, or add an image control to the form.
after you have that, you can use the following to get your desired effects.

#### No Border

Set form's `FormBoarderStyle` propery to `None`

#### Transparency

Set `Opacity` property of the Form to something less than 100%

#### Mouse over

Use `MouseHover` or `MouseEnter` events of the form

#### Overlay other windows

Set `TopMost` property of the form to true.

Comment: I still can't get the background of the form transparent with the image displaying at 100%

Comment: Just got it working, When I used White as the transparency key it didn't work but when I used black it did...